# Command "Break" doesnt work for some reason

Tags: python, break

```
number=input("enter a whole number")
if number.isdigit():
    print("Good one")
else:
    print ("haha, really clever")
answer=str(input("Wanna try again? y/n"))
if answer == 'n':
    print("Ok loser")
    break
elif answer== 'y':
    print("ok...good luck")
    continue
```

I tried to make a code that would react if the input is integer or float, and if its float it would restart if the person wants it to; but the command 'break' doesnt want to work for some reason please help... (make it simple please)

Comment: `break` needs a loop to operate. Where is yours ? what do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: What do you think `break` even means?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) will tell you how `break` works.  [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is worth working your way through.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your code with a `while` loop.

```
while True:
  number=input("enter a whole number")
  if number.isdigit():
    print("Good one")
  else:
    print ("haha, really clever")
  answer=str(input("Wanna try again? y/n"))
  if answer == 'n':
    print("Ok loser")
    break
  elif answer== 'y':
    print("ok...good luck")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a break, you need it to be in a loop (while, for, ...). A break stop the execution of the loop if it's condition is met. In your casse you only have ifs, so you don't need a break as it will not check the other conditions if the first one is met.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop.

```
answer = 'y'

while answer == 'y':
    number = input("Please enter a whole number: ")

    if number % 1 == 0:
        print("Good one!")
    else:
        print("Haha, really clever.")

     answer = input("Wanna try again? (y/n) ")
```

Set the answer to y so the loop runs at least once.

If the user wants to try again they enter y and the *condition* will be true meaning the loop wil run again.

Hope this helped!